# How denial of service is prevented in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In fabric or lets say in composer transactions are used to change ownership of some assets. The whole history of the owners of the assets is saved in the blockchain. I was wondering how DoS attack is prevented in fabric. If one or a group of peers do not endorse deliberately transactions invoked by a specific peer, would that cuase denial of service and if yes, how would that be prevented? Is it something that is already solved by selective endorsement,consensus mechanism used by Fabric, or some other part of the system is responsible to solve this issue? In proof of work it is not an issue as other peers are not acting maliciously and endorse at some point. But in a private blockchain like hyperledger fabric, where the number of peers is limited, how is it being solved?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its a private network mostly all the participants will be known and if someone is doing some malicious activity obviously the others will know about it and can work to revoke the access of malicious nodes. Moreover for example if there are three organizations participating and if the endorsement policy is set for approvals from 2 out of 3 then the third org cannot affect the network. And side by side as everyone has the view of whats happening with the ledger the malicious nodes can be kicked out of the network.

Comment: I see. Lets consider a scenario; lets say all the endorsers based on a policy are malicious and decide not to include transactions of a specific peer. In this case those transactions won't be appended to the ledger. But then it would be revealed and they would be punished. Unlike public blockchains that without determining the malicious nodes, others would continue validating the transactions. Is this right? Because I was thinking maybe the consensus mechanism is kind of preventing it.

Comment: Ya consensus also prevents malicious nodes..but then as you are saying all the endorserers are malicious then the admin must intervene and remove those peers.